# Auto indent code in an HTML file (generator/tool)

Tags: html

I was wondering if there is a tool or generator that could auto indent my code after production from:

```
<div>
<div>
<p>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div>
     <div>
          <p>
          </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try js-beautify](http://github.com/einars/js-beautify).

It's a JavaScript beautifier but works for HTML too.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Pretty Diff](http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify&l=html), which can also handle JSLT type tags.

Comment: Re *"JSLT"*: "JSLT" is similar to [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) and it is [a query and transformation language for JSON](https://github.com/schibsted/jslt), but do you mean [JSTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Standard_Tag_Library) (Jakarta Standard Tag Library)?

Comment: User *austincheney* has left the building, but perhaps somebody else can provide the necessary information?